# Is it possible to use values in a <span> as the parameters for a Ruby function?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

I'm passing a span to an HTML file from a javascript file using:

```
$('#eventCode').html event.code
```

From said HTML file I'm displaying the contents of the selected code with:

```
<span id="eventCode"></span>
```

This works fine, but I also am trying to make a ruby function call as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", Event.find_by_code("eventCode would go here"), 
    method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the event?" %>
```

Is there any way I can take the contents of a HTML span and use them as a parameter for a Ruby function, as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `link_to` tag is just a HTML `<a>` tag being rendered, you could pass your `event.code` directly to that tag ?

Uniquely identify your link with an id:

```
 <%= link_to "Delete", "Code name soon to be replaced", id: "eventCode-delete-link",  method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the event?" %>
```

and do something like this with your JS:

```
$('#eventCode-delete-link').html event.code
```

Would that work for your use case ?

EDIT

On second thought, if you want to pass your code name directly into `Event.find_by_code("codename")` then you won't be able to. In that case, you should handle this in a controller ahead of calling this probably.